# Can't Connect to Remote MySQL Database some times

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a Mysql DB Connected to ASP.NET MVC. In local it's working fine but when connected to a remote server sometimes it works fine and sometimes it has problems.

Any ideas to solve this problem would be appreciated.

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.
*************************
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host 'aleppo-cuisine.com' for user 'xxx' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```